# How can I make my site adjustable for different devices and not wider than my opened window?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for asking, but I have already tried all the tips I found in the Internet. Somehow the site is still well-looking only on my own computer and awfully bad on my smartphone. At least, I would like to have it narrower. Already've tried max-width.
[that's my site](http://ctr-sz.ru)

At the moment it looks like this in `"body"`

```
{

    background:  url(pics/background.png) ; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-width: 100%


    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If the whole code needed, I can attach it though there is nothing to be proud of.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515880/responsive-design

Comment: It is easier to switch to Responsive frameworks and once switched that 'll make your life easier. Bootstrap seems nice.

Comment: Your site doesn't have much content so you can easily switch to frameworks. For getting to know about Bootstrap, here is the link: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Do not visit the site in the question as it contains malware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is Responsive web design (RWD) to create sites for different device widths. Look it up on the internet to find many tutorials.

Also, I have noticed you are using table for creating the website layout. Creating layouts with tables will raise many issues. You should learn to create proper layouts first. http://learnlayout.com/ seems to have good tutorials.

An easier way is to use Twitter Bootstrap's grid system to create layouts. All you would be doing is adding classes to create proper layouts.

Comment: I was hoping there is an easier way, because I do not find myself able to cope with RWD, but thank you so much for bothering!

Comment: you can use Twitter bootstrap to do the job for you. You will need their grid system. All you have to do is use their classes.

Comment: haven't even thought about it! Thanks a lot!