# Is there a way to change values of padding for mobile only in bulma css framework?

Tags: html, css, bulma

So I built a website using Bulma css framework. I set the padding-left and padding-right for every element to 10%. On a mobile device the padding needs to be smaller. Maybe a 5% or less it doesn't matter. But I don't know how to change that padding for mobile devices only. I didn't find help in their documentation. Can someone help? For example:

```
nav{    
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
}
```

That I want to be:(but only for mobile devices)

```
nav{    
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Responsive Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515880/responsive-design)

Answer (score 2):

You can use media queries in css for assigning classes to specific devices. Please refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Example for mobile device:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .mobile-device {
        //styles for mobile
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bulma has [visibily helpers](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/visibility-helpers/) to show or hide elements depending on the device used (mobile, tablet, desktop, widescreen and fullHD).
You can apply the `is-hidden-tablet` class to your `nav` in HTML and use it like this in your CSS:

```
nav.is-hidden-tablet{    
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
```

to have a navigation menu displayed only on mobile with your custom padding.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Example with Sass mixin

```
nav {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

@include mobile {
  nav {
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
  }
}
```

[Named mixins](https://bulma.io/documentation/utilities/responsive-mixins/#named-mixins)

Answer (score 0):

You can look into mixins provided by bulma to define your own [rules](https://bulma.io/documentation/utilities/responsive-mixins/).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).